# What Kind of compressing is that

Tags: javascript, compression

This is the code of the compressed file! 
It's clearly obfuscated and it's hard to dechiffer

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('5 G(b,a){b.N().V(G,n.o.2Z);4.I=b;4.2E=b.N().2y();4.M=a;4.C=t;4.q=t;4.16=t;4.1o=w;4.K(b.v())}G.6.2F=5(){7 d=4;7 g;7 f;4.q=3A.3u("1Y");4.q.5p=4.2E;9(4.1o){4.2a()}4.4O().4H.4B(4.q);4.2X=n.o.u.1G(4.v(),"4b",5(){f=g});n.o.u.1E(4.q,"42",5(){g=H;f=w});n.o.u.1E(4.q,"2M",5(e){g=w;9(!f){7 c;7 b;7 a=d.I.N();n.o.u.X(a,"2M",d.I);n.o.u.X(a,"3V",d.I);9(a.2B()){b=a.1y();c=d.I.1s();a.v().1V(c);1U(5(){a.v().1V(c);9(b!==t&&(a.v().17()>b)){a.v().3F(b+1)}},3z)}e.3w=H;9(e.2j){e.2j()}}});n.o.u.1E(4.q,"2U",5(){7 a=d.I.N();n.o.u.X(a,"2U",d.I)});n.o.u.1E(4.q,"2L",5(){7 a=d.I.N();n.o.u.X(a,"2L",d.I)})};G.6.2Q=5(){9(4.q&&4.q.3e){4.1F();n.o.u.3b(4.2X);n.o.u.57(4.q);4.q.3e.4Z(4.q);4.q=t}};G.6.38=5(){9(4.1o){7 a=4.28(4.C);4.q.U.1J=a.y+"z";4.q.U.1H=a.x+"z"}};G.6.1F=5(){9(4.q){4.q.U.36="2V"}4.1o=w};G.6.2a=5(){9(4.q){7 e="";7 c=4.3g.4j(" ");7 b=12(c[0].1N(),10);7 d=12(c[1].1N(),10);7 a=4.28(4.C);4.q.U.43=4.2P(a);e="<41 3Z=\'"+4.2O+"\' U=\'20: 1Z; 1J: "+d+"z; 1H: "+b+"z; ";9(!4.I.N().1l){e+="3Y: 3X("+(-1*d)+"z, "+((-1*b)+4.1r)+"z, "+((-1*d)+4.1k)+"z, "+(-1*b)+"z);"}e+="\'>";4.q.3W=e+"<1Y U=\'"+"20: 1Z;"+"1J: "+4.1X[0]+"z;"+"1H: "+4.1X[1]+"z;"+"3T: "+4.2D+";"+"1O-1f: "+4.2z+"z;"+"1O-3P: "+4.2v+";"+"1O-3N: "+4.2t+";"+"1O-U: "+4.2s+";"+"1w-3I: "+4.2o+";"+"1w-3E: 1h;"+"1x: "+4.1r+"z;"+"3B-1u:"+4.1k+"z;"+"\'>"+4.16.1w+"</1Y>";9(1Q 4.16.14==="15"||4.16.14===""){4.q.14=4.I.N().2G()}L{4.q.14=4.16.14}4.q.U.36=""}4.1o=H};G.6.3i=5(a){4.16=a;7 b=A.3p(0,a.2T-1);b=A.22(4.M.p-1,b);7 c=4.M[b];4.2O=c.3f;4.1k=c.1u;4.1r=c.1x;4.1X=c.5m||[0,0];4.2c=c.5g||[12(4.1k/2,10),12(4.1r/2,10)];4.2D=c.5b||"55";4.2z=c.51||11;4.2o=c.4V||"2V";4.2t=c.4T||"4R";4.2s=c.4N||"4K";4.2v=c.4J||"4I,4G-4F";4.3g=c.4D||"0 0"};G.6.3h=5(a){4.C=a};G.6.2P=5(b){7 a=[];a.Y("4A: 4y;");a.Y("20: 1Z; 1J: "+b.y+"z; 1H: "+b.x+"z;");a.Y("1x: "+4.1r+"z; 1u: "+4.1k+"z;");j a.4v("")};G.6.28=5(b){7 a=4.37().1P(b);a.x-=4.2c[1];a.y-=4.2c[0];a.x=12(a.x,10);a.y=12(a.y,10);j a};5 D(a){4.W=a;4.Q=a.v();4.T=a.3c();4.13=a.2S();4.18=a.3a();4.k=[];4.C=t;4.2e=t;4.Z=F G(4,a.23())}D.6.45=5(){j 4.k.p};D.6.1D=5(){j 4.k};D.6.2R=5(){j 4.C};D.6.v=5(){j 4.Q};D.6.N=5(){j 4.W};D.6.1s=5(){7 i;7 b=F n.o.1m(4.C,4.C);7 a=4.1D();B(i=0;i<a.p;i++){b.V(a[i].S())}j b};D.6.1C=5(){4.Z.K(t);4.k=[];21 4.k};D.6.1B=5(e){7 i;7 c;7 b;9(4.2N(e)){j w}9(!4.C){4.C=e.S();4.25()}L{9(4.18){7 l=4.k.p+1;7 a=(4.C.O()*(l-1)+e.S().O())/l;7 d=(4.C.19()*(l-1)+e.S().19())/l;4.C=F n.o.1q(a,d);4.25()}}e.1p=H;4.k.Y(e);c=4.k.p;b=4.W.1y();9(b!==t&&4.Q.17()>b){9(e.v()!==4.Q){e.K(4.Q)}}L 9(c<4.13){9(e.v()!==4.Q){e.K(4.Q)}}L 9(c===4.13){B(i=0;i<c;i++){4.k[i].K(t)}}L{e.K(t)}4.2K();j H};D.6.2J=5(a){j 4.2e.2I(a.S())};D.6.25=5(){7 a=F n.o.1m(4.C,4.C);4.2e=4.W.2f(a)};D.6.2K=5(){7 c=4.k.p;7 a=4.W.1y();9(a!==t&&4.Q.17()>a){4.Z.1F();j}9(c<4.13){4.Z.1F();j}7 b=4.W.23().p;7 d=4.W.2H()(4.k,b);4.Z.3h(4.C);4.Z.3i(d);4.Z.2a()};D.6.2N=5(a){7 i;9(4.k.1d){j 4.k.1d(a)!==-1}L{B(i=0;i<4.k.p;i++){9(a===4.k[i]){j H}}}j w};5 8(a,c,b){4.V(8,n.o.2Z);c=c||[];b=b||{};4.k=[];4.E=[];4.1j=[];4.1e=t;4.1i=w;4.T=b.3U||3S;4.13=b.3R||2;4.1W=b.2C||t;4.M=b.3Q||[];4.2d=b.14||"";4.1z=H;9(b.2A!==15){4.1z=b.2A}4.18=w;9(b.2k!==15){4.18=b.2k}4.1a=w;9(b.2x!==15){4.1a=b.2x}4.1l=w;9(b.2w!==15){4.1l=b.2w}4.1I=b.3O||8.2u;4.1t=b.3L||8.2g;4.1c=b.3J||8.2r;4.1T=b.3H||8.2p;4.1R=b.3G||8.2n;4.1v=b.3D||8.2m;4.1S=b.3C||"P";9(3K.3y.3M().1d("3x")!==-1){4.1R=4.1v}4.2q();4.2l(c,H);4.K(a)}8.6.2F=5(){7 a=4;4.1e=4.v();4.1i=H;4.1b();4.1j=[n.o.u.1G(4.v(),"3v",5(){a.1A(w);9(4.17()===(4.2i("3t")||0)||4.17()===4.2i("2C")){n.o.u.X(4,"2h")}}),n.o.u.1G(4.v(),"2h",5(){a.1n()})]};8.6.2Q=5(){7 i;B(i=0;i<4.k.p;i++){9(4.k[i].v()!==4.1e){4.k[i].K(4.1e)}}B(i=0;i<4.E.p;i++){4.E[i].1C()}4.E=[];B(i=0;i<4.1j.p;i++){n.o.u.3b(4.1j[i])}4.1j=[];4.1e=t;4.1i=w};8.6.38=5(){};8.6.2q=5(){7 i,1f;9(4.M.p>0){j}B(i=0;i<4.1c.p;i++){1f=4.1c[i];4.M.Y({3f:4.1I+(i+1)+"."+4.1t,1u:1f,1x:1f})}};8.6.3s=5(){7 i;7 a=4.1D();7 b=F n.o.1m();B(i=0;i<a.p;i++){b.V(a[i].S())}4.v().1V(b)};8.6.3c=5(){j 4.T};8.6.3r=5(a){4.T=a};8.6.2S=5(){j 4.13};8.6.3q=5(a){4.13=a};8.6.1y=5(){j 4.1W};8.6.40=5(a){4.1W=a};8.6.23=5(){j 4.M};8.6.3o=5(a){4.M=a};8.6.2G=5(){j 4.2d};8.6.3n=5(a){4.2d=a};8.6.2B=5(){j 4.1z};8.6.3m=5(a){4.1z=a};8.6.3a=5(){j 4.18};8.6.44=5(a){4.18=a};8.6.3l=5(){j 4.1a};8.6.3k=5(a){4.1a=a};8.6.3j=5(){j 4.1l};8.6.48=5(a){4.1l=a};8.6.5o=5(){j 4.1t};8.6.5n=5(a){4.1t=a};8.6.5l=5(){j 4.1I};8.6.5k=5(a){4.1I=a};8.6.5i=5(){j 4.1c};8.6.5h=5(a){4.1c=a};8.6.2H=5(){j 4.1T};8.6.5f=5(a){4.1T=a};8.6.5e=5(){j 4.1v};8.6.5d=5(a){4.1v=a};8.6.2y=5(){j 4.1S};8.6.5c=5(a){4.1S=a};8.6.1D=5(){j 4.k};8.6.5a=5(){j 4.k.p};8.6.59=5(){j 4.E};8.6.54=5(){j 4.E.p};8.6.1B=5(b,a){4.2b(b);9(!a){4.1n()}};8.6.2l=5(b,a){7 c;B(c 39 b){9(b.50(c)){4.2b(b[c])}}9(!a){4.1n()}};8.6.2b=5(b){9(b.4X()){7 a=4;n.o.u.1G(b,"4W",5(){9(a.1i){4.1p=w;a.1b()}})}b.1p=w;4.k.Y(b)};8.6.4U=5(c,a){7 b=4.29(c);9(!a&&b){4.1b()}j b};8.6.4S=5(a,c){7 i,r;7 b=w;B(i=0;i<a.p;i++){r=4.29(a[i]);b=b||r}9(!c&&b){4.1b()}j b};8.6.29=5(b){7 i;7 a=-1;9(4.k.1d){a=4.k.1d(b)}L{B(i=0;i<4.k.p;i++){9(b===4.k[i]){a=i;4Q}}}9(a===-1){j w}b.K(t);4.k.4P(a,1);j H};8.6.4M=5(){4.1A(H);4.k=[]};8.6.1b=5(){7 a=4.E.4L();4.E=[];4.1A(w);4.1n();1U(5(){7 i;B(i=0;i<a.p;i++){a[i].1C()}},0)};8.6.2f=5(d){7 f=4.37();7 c=F n.o.1q(d.27().O(),d.27().19());7 a=F n.o.1q(d.24().O(),d.24().19());7 e=f.1P(c);e.x+=4.T;e.y-=4.T;7 g=f.1P(a);g.x-=4.T;g.y+=4.T;7 b=f.32(e);7 h=f.32(g);d.V(b);d.V(h);j d};8.6.1n=5(){4.26(0)};8.6.1A=5(a){7 i,J;B(i=0;i<4.E.p;i++){4.E[i].1C()}4.E=[];B(i=0;i<4.k.p;i++){J=4.k[i];J.1p=w;9(a){J.K(t)}}};8.6.30=5(b,e){7 R=4E;7 g=(e.O()-b.O())*A.1K/1M;7 f=(e.19()-b.19())*A.1K/1M;7 a=A.1L(g/2)*A.1L(g/2)+A.31(b.O()*A.1K/1M)*A.31(e.O()*A.1K/1M)*A.1L(f/2)*A.1L(f/2);7 c=2*A.4C(A.2Y(a),A.2Y(1-a));7 d=R*c;j d};8.6.35=5(b,a){j a.2I(b.S())};8.6.33=5(c){7 i,d,P,1h;7 a=4z;7 b=t;B(i=0;i<4.E.p;i++){P=4.E[i];1h=P.2R();9(1h){d=4.30(1h,c.S());9(d<a){a=d;b=P}}}9(b&&b.2J(c)){b.1B(c)}L{P=F D(4);P.1B(c);4.E.Y(P)}};8.6.26=5(e){7 i,J;7 d;7 c=4;9(!4.1i){j}9(e===0){n.o.u.X(4,"4x",4);9(1Q 4.1g!=="15"){4w(4.1g);21 4.1g}}9(4.v().17()>3){d=F n.o.1m(4.v().1s().24(),4.v().1s().27())}L{d=F n.o.1m(F n.o.1q(34.4u,-2W.4t),F n.o.1q(-34.4s,2W.4r))}7 a=4.2f(d);7 b=A.22(e+4.1R,4.k.p);B(i=e;i<b;i++){J=4.k[i];9(!J.1p&&4.35(J,a)){9(!4.1a||(4.1a&&J.4q())){4.33(J)}}}9(b<4.k.p){4.1g=1U(5(){c.26(b)},0)}L{21 4.1g;n.o.u.X(4,"4Y",4)}};8.6.V=5(d,c){j(5(b){7 a;B(a 39 b.6){4.6[a]=b.6[a]}j 4}).4p(d,[c])};8.2p=5(a,c){7 f=0;7 b="";7 d=a.p.4o();7 e=d;4n(e!==0){e=12(e/10,10);f++}f=A.22(f,c);j{1w:d,2T:f,14:b}};8.2n=52;8.2m=4m;8.2u="4l://n-o-4k-58-4i.4h.4g/4f/4e/4d/4c/m";8.2g="4a";8.2r=[53,56,5j,49,47];9(1Q 3d.6.1N!==\'5\'){3d.6.1N=5(){j 4.46(/^\\s+|\\s+$/g,\'\')}}',62,336,'||||this|function|prototype|var|MarkerClusterer|if||||||||||return|markers_|||google|maps|length|div_|||null|event|getMap|false|||px|Math|for|center_|Cluster|clusters_|new|ClusterIcon|true|cluster_|marker|setMap|else|styles_|getMarkerClusterer|lat|cluster|map_||getPosition|gridSize_|style|extend|markerClusterer_|trigger|push|clusterIcon_|||parseInt|minClusterSize_|title|undefined|sums_|getZoom|averageCenter_|lng|ignoreHidden_|repaint|imageSizes_|indexOf|activeMap_|size|timerRefStatic|center|ready_|listeners_|height_|enableRetinaIcons_|LatLngBounds|redraw_|visible_|isAdded|LatLng|width_|getBounds|imageExtension_|height|batchSizeIE_|text|width|getMaxZoom|zoomOnClick_|resetViewport_|addMarker|remove|getMarkers|addDomListener|hide|addListener|left|imagePath_|top|PI|sin|180|trim|font|fromLatLngToDivPixel|typeof|batchSize_|clusterClass_|calculator_|setTimeout|fitBounds|maxZoom_|anchorText_|div|absolute|position|delete|min|getStyles|getSouthWest|calculateBounds_|createClusters_|getNorthEast|getPosFromLatLng_|removeMarker_|show|pushMarkerTo_|anchorIcon_|title_|bounds_|getExtendedBounds|IMAGE_EXTENSION|idle|get|stopPropagation|averageCenter|addMarkers|BATCH_SIZE_IE|BATCH_SIZE|textDecoration_|CALCULATOR|setupStyles_|IMAGE_SIZES|fontStyle_|fontWeight_|IMAGE_PATH|fontFamily_|enableRetinaIcons|ignoreHidden|getClusterClass|textSize_|zoomOnClick|getZoomOnClick|maxZoom|textColor_|className_|onAdd|getTitle|getCalculator|contains|isMarkerInClusterBounds|updateIcon_|mouseout|click|isMarkerAlreadyAdded_|url_|createCss|onRemove|getCenter|getMinimumClusterSize|index|mouseover|none|178|boundsChangedListener_|sqrt|OverlayView|distanceBetweenPoints_|cos|fromDivPixelToLatLng|addToClosestCluster_|85|isMarkerInBounds_|display|getProjection|draw|in|getAverageCenter|removeListener|getGridSize|String|parentNode|url|backgroundPosition_|setCenter|useStyle|getEnableRetinaIcons|setIgnoreHidden|getIgnoreHidden|setZoomOnClick|setTitle|setStyles|max|setMinimumClusterSize|setGridSize|fitMapToMarkers|minZoom|createElement|zoom_changed|cancelBubble|msie|userAgent|100|document|line|clusterClass|batchSizeIE|align|setZoom|batchSize|calculator|decoration|imageSizes|navigator|imageExtension|toLowerCase|weight|imagePath|family|styles|minimumClusterSize|60|color|gridSize|clusterclick|innerHTML|rect|clip|src|setMaxZoom|img|mousedown|cssText|setAverageCenter|getSize|replace|90|setEnableRetinaIcons|78|png|bounds_changed|images|markerclustererplus|trunk|svn|com|googlecode|v3|split|utility|https|500|while|toString|apply|getVisible|00048865625|08136444384544|48388434375|02070771743472|join|clearTimeout|clusteringbegin|pointer|40000|cursor|appendChild|atan2|backgroundPosition|6371|serif|sans|overlayMouseTarget|Arial|fontFamily|normal|slice|clearMarkers|fontStyle|getPanes|splice|break|bold|removeMarkers|fontWeight|removeMarker|textDecoration|dragend|getDraggable|clusteringend|removeChild|hasOwnProperty|textSize|2000||getTotalClusters|black||clearInstanceListeners|library|getClusters|getTotalMarkers|textColor|setClusterClass|setBatchSizeIE|getBatchSizeIE|setCalculator|anchorIcon|setImageSizes|getImageSizes|66|setImagePath|getImagePath|anchorText|setImageExtension|getImageExtension|className'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: Its minified and packed.

Comment: you can use jsbeautifier.org or unpacker for your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this http://matthewfl.com/unPacker.html to unpack

It worked to me

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is called JavaScript-minification.

**What minification does:**

- Delete line breaks and whitespaces
- Replace long object names with one character names
- Other minor optimizations that result in less code

This way the size of the script is reduced remarkably. One example of a library that allows minification but also deminification is [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).